# I want to add 4 days to the created_at column for all records in a database. Is there a way to do this in the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a bunch of records in a database where i want to update the "created_at" column. Is there a way in the rails console that I can access every record in the database and add, let's say 4 days, to the created_at column?

I've tried looking up other answers but none have really helped especially when trying to add days or  months to all records for the created_at column.

I'm using PostgreSql

Comment: Every record across all tables? Any reason a) you would need to do this? b) you would like to falsify when the records were actually created? `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table_name SET created_at = DateAdd(d,4,created_at)")` will do it for a single table if you really must

Comment: Thanks. Essentially yes I just want to see if it was indeed possible to change when records were created. I tried running what you said but no luck. I'm using PostgreSQl btw.

Comment: Okay try `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table_name SET created_at = created_at + interval '4 days'")` in Postgres

Comment: Awesome it worked! Thank you!

Comment: The `rails` way is: `Model.find_each { |m| m.update(created_at: m.created_at + 4.days) }`

Answer (score 0):

Try executing following line of code:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE TABLE_NAME(NOT MODEL NAME) SET updated_at = updated_at + interval '4 days'")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - why should one try to execute that line?